# ng-href="#/myanchor" not working anymore as usual with angularjs 1.6.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor, angularjs-ng-href

I used to work with angularjs 1.5.8. For professional reasons I need to migrate to version 1.6.1 and I need to use ng-href to go to an anchor that I configured.

So when I write in my code:

```
<a ng-href="#/rubric/{{ data }}">link</a>
```

In my browser, when I click "link", I have in the address bar:

- With angularjs 1.5.8, I get this :

  `mywebsite/#/rubric/AOO` which is exactly what I want

But

- With angularjs 1.6.1, I get this :

  `mywebsite/#!#%rubric%2FAOO` which is not what I want

Please, where is the problem ? Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace it with:

```
<a ng-href="#!/rubric/{{ data }}">link</a>
```

you should add `!` in ng-href